# How to filter Chart JavaScript Dashboard by Year through dropdown after the MySQL count query?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, chart.js

I am struggling right now. I was able to get the counts of certain rows on my student table and reflect them on my dashboard charts with Chart JavaScript but now I need to filter the charts by academic year through a dropdown.

so here's my dashboard. Actually I needed to filter these charts by academic year and by course but to lessen the complexity I just made separate pages for each course(as you can see on the left sidebar) so the query is injected directly to the specific course with course name. But now, I need to filter them by academic year, I was to able to populate the academic year on the dropdown but I just don't how to do the real thing or make it work. :
[image: so here's my dashboard. Actually I needed to filter these charts by academic year and by course but to lessen the complexity I just made separate pages for each course(as you can see on the left sidebar) so the query is injected directly to the specific course with course name. But now, I need to filter them by academic year, I was to able to populate the academic year on the dropdown but I just don't how to do the real thing or make it work.]

so here's my chart_data.php sample (this is the code I used to reflect the counts of gender on gender chart)

```
<?php

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'eprs';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';

try{
$dbcon = new PDO("mysql:host={$dbhost};dbname={$dbname}",$dbuser,$dbpass);
$dbcon->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

}catch(PDOException $ex){
die($ex->getMessage());
}
///BA ENGLISH STARTS

//FETCH GENDER DATA
$stmt=$dbcon->prepare("SELECT gender, COUNT(*) AS count FROM student WHERE course = 'BA ENGLISH'    GROUP BY gender;");
$stmt->execute();
$labels_gender_baeng=[];
$counts_gender_baeng = [];
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $labels_gender_baeng[]= $row['gender'];
    $counts_gender_baeng[] = $row['count'];
}
?>
```

here's the javasrcipt with Chart JavaScript in my BAENG.php (BAENG is short Bachelor of Arts in English)

```
<script>
//GENDER CHART
var ctx = document.getElementById("gender_baeng").getContext('2d');

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: <?php echo json_encode($labels_gender_baeng);?>,
        datasets: [{
            data: <?php echo json_encode($counts_gender_baeng);?>,
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderColor: '#eff1f0',
            fill: false
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: true, // Add to prevent default behaviour of full-width/height
        plugins: {
            colorschemes: {
                scheme: 'brewer.DarkTwo8'
            }

        },
        legend: {
            labels: {
                // This more specific font property overrides the global property
                fontColor: '#eff1f0',
                fontFamily: 'consolas',
                fontSize: 15,
                fontStyle: 'bold'
            }
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Now, here's the dropdown button in my BAENG.php

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
   <div class="btn-group dropleft" role="group">
      <button name="acadYear" id="acadYear" type="button" class="btn btn1 dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
       A.Y.
       </button>
       <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="acadYear">
          <?php
             foreach($result as $row)
               {
                echo '<a class="dropdown-item"  value="'.$row["acadYear"].'">'.$row["acadYear"].'</a>';
                }
                  ?>
             </div>
       </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn1" title="download PDF">
               <i class="fas fa-download"></i>
             </button>
     </div>
```

And the code to populate my dropdown

```
$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=eprs", "root", "");

$query = "SELECT acadYear FROM student WHERE course = 'BA ENGLISH' GROUP BY acadYear DESC";

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();
```

These codes are working but can you add something to it to achieve what I am looking for? I just need to filter my charts by academic year with that dropdown as you can on the linked picture.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if you got a solution for this. First of all, i don't think the  should have the value. try using a list maybe. Also, i would use a js event listener here. maybe on click.